# UDP winsock chat program receives -1 from recvfrom() and sendto()

Tags: c, mfc, udp, winsock

Currently, we are producing UDP chat programs using MFC and C.

I'm working on both bind because I have to send incoming messages from the server and client.

An error occurs when recvfrom() and sendto(), they return -1.

I don't know what the problem is. I searched it and did what I did, but it's not working.

Why does `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` return -1?

I don't know what the problem is.

**server Code**

```
static UINT UdpServerFunc(LPVOID pVoid)
{
    CServerDlg *dlg = (CServerDlg *)AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd;

    //------------------------------------------------------
    CString slniPath;
    slniPath.Format(_T("./NetworkPath.ini"));
    TCHAR ServerPort[MAX_PATH];
    int ServerPort_Num;
    GetPrivateProfileString(_T("ServerInfo"), _T("Port"), _T(""), ServerPort, MAX_PATH, slniPath);
    ServerPort_Num = _ttoi(ServerPort);
    //------------------------------------------------------

    //Startup Winsock 
    WSADATA wsaData; 
    int retval = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData); 
    if (retval != 0) 
    {
        AfxMessageBox("WSAStartup() Error\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //SOCKET
    dlg->server_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);//IPPROTO_UDP or PPROTO_HOPOPTS
    if (dlg->server_sock == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("Socket() Error\n");
        return 0;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&dlg->server_addr, sizeof(dlg-> server_addr));
    dlg->server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dlg->server_addr.sin_port = htons(ServerPort_Num); //30112
    dlg->server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
    
    dlg->client_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dlg->client_addr.sin_port = htons(ServerPort_Num);
    dlg->client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    

    retval = bind(dlg->server_sock, (SOCKADDR*)&dlg->server_addr, sizeof(dlg->server_addr));

    AfxMessageBox("server start");
    if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        AfxMessageBox("bind() ERROR\n");
        return -1;
    }
    //Data Communication
    int addrlength;
    char buf[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int recv_size;
    while (1)
    {       
        //recvfrom()
        addrlength = sizeof(dlg->client_addr);  
        recv_size = recvfrom(dlg->server_sock, reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf), BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&dlg->client_addr, &addrlength);
        if (recv_size == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            AfxMessageBox("recvfrom() Error");
            break;
        }
        //Data print
        buf[recv_size] = '\0';
        CString strMsg;
        strMsg = CString(buf, recv_size);
        dlg->m_ListChat.AddString(strMsg);
        strMsg = "";

    }
    closesocket(dlg->server_sock);
    WSACleanup;
}
```

**Server Sendto Code**

```
void CServerDlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
    CServerDlg *dlg = (CServerDlg *)AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd;
    
    CString strText = _T("");
    char Text[BUFFER_SIZE];
    dlg->m_edit_chat.GetWindowText(strText);
    strcpy(Text, strText);
    int send_size = sendto(dlg->server_sock, Text, strlen(Text), 0, (sockaddr*)&dlg->client_addr, sizeof(dlg->client_addr));
    if (send_size == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("sendto() Error");
    }
    else
    {
        dlg->m_ListChat.AddString(strText);
    }

}
```

**Client Code**

```
static UINT ClientUdpThreadFunc(LPVOID pVOID) {

    CClientTestDlg *dlg = (CClientTestDlg *)AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd;
    CString slniPath;
    slniPath.Format(_T("./NetworkPath.ini"));

    TCHAR ServerPort[MAX_PATH];
    int ServerPort_Num;
    GetPrivateProfileString(_T("ServerInfo"), _T("Port"), _T(""), ServerPort, MAX_PATH, slniPath);
    ServerPort_Num = _ttoi(ServerPort); //30112

    TCHAR ServerIp[MAX_PATH];
    int ServerIp_Num;
    GetPrivateProfileString(_T("ServerInfo"), _T("IP"), _T(""), ServerIp, MAX_PATH, slniPath);
    ServerIp_Num = _ttoi(ServerIp); //127.0.0.1
    //--------------------------------------------------

    //StartUp Winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int retval = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (retval != 0)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("WSAStartup() Error\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //socket
    dlg->clnt_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP); 
    if (dlg->clnt_sock == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("socket() Error"));
        return 0;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&dlg->ServerAddr, sizeof(dlg->ServerAddr));
    dlg->ServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    dlg->ServerAddr.sin_port = htons(ServerPort_Num); 
    dlg->ServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVERIP); 
    /*
    dlg->FromServer.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dlg->FromServer.sin_port = htons(ServerPort_Num);
    dlg->FromServer.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVERIP);
    */
    retval = bind(dlg->clnt_sock, (SOCKADDR*)&dlg->ServerAddr, sizeof(dlg->ServerAddr));
    
    if (retval == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        AfxMessageBox("bind() ERROR\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    //Data Communication
    CString strMsg;
    int addrlength;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    int recv_size;

    while (1) {
        addrlength = sizeof(dlg->FromServer);
        recv_size = recvfrom(dlg->clnt_sock, reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf), BUF_SIZE, 0, (sockaddr*)&dlg->FromServer, &addrlength);
        if (recv_size == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            AfxMessageBox("recvfrom() ERROR");
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            //Data print
            buf[recv_size] = '\0';
            strMsg = CString(buf, recv_size);
            dlg->m_listChat.AddString(strMsg);
            strMsg = "";
        }
    

    }       
    
    closesocket(dlg->clnt_sock);
    WSACleanup;
}
```

**Client Sendto Code**

```
void CClientTestDlg::OnBnClickedButtonSend()
{

    CClientTestDlg *dlg = (CClientTestDlg *)AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd;
    
    CString UdpStrText = _T("");
    char Text[BUF_SIZE];
    m_editChat.GetWindowText(UdpStrText);
    strcpy(Text, UdpStrText);
    int UdpRtn;
    UdpRtn = sendto(dlg->clnt_sock, Text, strlen(Text), 0, (SOCKADDR*)&dlg->ServerAddr, sizeof(dlg->ServerAddr));
    if (UdpRtn == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("sendto() ERROR\n %s");
        
    }
    closesocket(dlg->clnt_sock);
    
}
```

Comment: "*Why does `sendto()` and `recvfrom()` return -1?*" - they both return `SOCKET_ERROR` (-1) on failure. Use `WSAGetLastError()` to find out why they failed.

Comment: You are binding the client socket to the server's IP, which is wrong. You need to bind to the client's local IP instead (or INADDR_ANY), and then send to the server's IP.

Comment: Also, `buf[recv_size] = '\0';` is a buffer overflow if `recv_size` is exactly `BUFFER_SIZE`. Since you are using `recv_size` when constructing a `CString`, you don't need to null-terminate the buffer at all. You are making this mistake on both client and server.

Comment: Re "*You need to bind to*", No need to bind the client at all.

Comment: I will Try soon

Comment: `strcpy(Text, UdpStrText);` - That's superfluous, and a buffer overflow. Just use `UdpStrText`. It also knows its length, so `strlen(Text)` is equally superfluous. `strMsg = CString(buf, recv_size);` - That's also not at all needed. Just write into the `CString` instance. Clearly, you have opted for `MBCS` project settings.

Comment: @ikegami the client is doing `recvfrom()`, so it needs to be bound first so it knows which interface(s) and port to receive on.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, Nope. By default, it binds to every interface on a random port number. This is already the ideal situation. The server simply needs to send its response to the source addr + source port of the request.

Comment: @LieuRabbit again, you are neglecting to show what error you are getting. All Winsock functions report an error code on failure (via `WSAGetLastError()`, except for `WSAStartup()` which reports an error code via its return value instead). Nowhere in your code are you logging those error codes. So, what error code are you actually getting? And is it on the client side, or the server side, or both? Be more specific.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau When I change ```dlg->ServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVERIP); ``` to ``INADDR_ANY``  The Error is C++ Runtime Library Error I can't check Error code with WSAGetLastError() In Client

Comment: @LieuRabbit you can't get C++ Runtime Library errors from making Winsock function calls. Something else is going on that you haven't described. For instance, who exactly is calling `ClientUdpThreadFunc()` and `UdpServerFunc()`? Those look like thread functions. How are you creating the threads? And why are you using `AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd` to pass data into the threads, instead of using their own input parameters? And what is `m_pMainWnd` exactly? Its name suggests it's an `HWND`, not a class object pointer, like you are casting it to. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'll organize it quickly and upload it again so that it's easy to see

Comment: @LieuRabbit your typecasts of `AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd` look very suspicious, so your `dlg` pointers are also suspicious. Passing invalid memory into Winsock functions would be *undefined behavior*, so anything could happen, including crashes, runtime errors, corrupted memory, etc. Also, it is not possible for a Winsock function to fail and not report an error code, so if you are getting error code 0 then it can only mean you made another system call that wiped out the error code before you retrieved the error code.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau TCP uses ``AfxGetApp()' to make it work well. I'll upload the entire code in 30 minutes.

Comment: @LieuRabbit "*I'll upload the entire code*" - please don't do that. StackOverflow is not a debugging service. Strip the code down to the **bare minimum** needed to reproduce the same problem, and then post that code instead.. Read about what a [mcve] actually is.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Then I'll try everything I can and tell you

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I insert ``sendto`` before ``while`` in Client and It's work Thank you